# (Java) Trying to animate an arraylist of coins with a (working) animation class

Tags: java, 2d, android, libgdx, animation

I have a coin class which takes in an integer `numOfCoins`and an enum `LayoutType`, which can be linear or curved. A linear layout displays the coins in a straight line one after the other - we'll work with this since the method is small and straight forward.

My constructor looks like this:

```
public Coin(float xPos, float yPos, int numOfCoins, LayoutType layout) {
        setType(ObjectType.COIN);
        coinList = new ArrayList<Coin>(); // arraylist of coins
        setPos(xPos, yPos); // set starting position of coin(s)
        if (layout == LayoutType.LINEAR)) {
            linearLayout(); // display coins in a straight line
        } else if (layout == LayoutType.CURVE{
            curveLayout();
        }

}
```

And my `linearLayout()` method looks like this

```
public void linearLayout() {
        //draw numOfCoins amount of coins in a straight line
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCoins; i++) {
            Coin coin = new Coin(xPos, yPos);
            coinList.add(coin);
            xPos += 50; // place coins 50 pixels apart 
        }
}
```

I have a working animation class and a spritesheet for the coins - however, the way I have modelled my coins is in such a way that 1 coin object can contain `numOfCoins` amount of coins, so I can't just directly call the animation in the draw method.

The class' `draw()` method is in an abstract class `GameObject` which `Coin` extends. It looks like this:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    // if the object is a coin iterate through the list of coins
    // and draw the sprites, if it isn't a coin, simply draw the objects sprite
    if (type == ObjectType.COIN) {
        for (Coin coin : getCoinList()) {
            coin.getCoinList().draw(batch);
        }
    } else {
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

This draw() method is called in World.render().

How would I create an animation using my `Animator`class for each coin if I have 6 coins in a straight line for instance? I can't seem to find a way. Highly grateful for any help, thanks.

Comment: If `draw()` is overridden for Coin class, why does it check `if (type == ObjectType.COIN)`? It's hard to say how your Animator class should interact with Coin as you didn't give any details of the Animator class.

Answer (score 1):

Are all coins doing the same animation? You could make a method in the `Animation` class that takes a coin as an argument, then performs the animation on that coin. Then, on another class, you make a loop that traverses the coin list and calls the method in your `Animation` class, therefore animating each coin as you go through the list. You can also add delay between each coin animation.

By the way, I'm just curious, you have a `coinList` inside `Coin`, and everytime the constructor is called, you call `linearLayout, which adds`numOfCoin` number of coins in the list. Isn't it adding unnecessary coins?